# Apache RewriteRule with ampersand in new URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried to rewrite this URL

`https://www.test.com/blog/post/41/postname.html`

to

`https://www.test.com/content.php?coId=11&postId=41`

by

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\/blog\/post\/([0-9]*)\/(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule (.*) /content.php?coId=11&wpPostId=%2 [QSA,L]
```

However, the ampersand in the RewriteRule is probably not correctly escaped and I have not found any solution how to do this. According to the htaccess tester at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be it is converted to

```
https://www.test.com/content.php?coId=11416wpPostId=41
```

which means that the ampersand is replaced by '416'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this simple rule for this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([^/]+)/[\w-]+\.html$ index.php?coId=11&wpPostId=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.